# Closing 3D map views via Python

Tags: pyqgis, 3d

I have some 3D map views open in my QGIS session and would like to close them all via Python. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a really clean way but this would close all the dock widgets that are named title as 3D maps (in the local language):

```
unformatted_title_string = QCoreApplication.translate("QgsLayoutItem3DMap", "3D Map %1")
window_title_prefix = unformatted_title_string[:unformatted_title_string.index("%")]

for child in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
    if child.windowTitle().startswith(window_title_prefix):
        child.close()
```

QGIS might crash sooner or later but that might just be the state of 3D maps at the moment... Theoretically this should be the same as closing the dock widget as a user with the "x" button.